# Unrecognized expression in js script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new into `js` at all and will need some help with this. This is my `vote.js` script

```
 function vote(type, value, image_id) {
   var dataFields = {'type': type, 'value': value, 'image_id': image_id};

   var ThisImageVotes = $("#"+image_id).find('#'+type).html();

   $.ajax({ // Ajax
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_vots.php",
      data: dataFields,
      timeout: 3000,
      success: function(dataBack){
         $("#"+image_id).find('#'+type).html(dataBack); 
           if(type=='positive')
           {
                 $("#"+image_id).find('#voteUp a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="return false;"></a>');
           }
           else if(type=='negative')
           {
                 $("#"+image_id).find('#voteDown a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="return false;"></a>');
           }

         $("#"+image_id).find('#voteUp("#"+image_id).find("#voteUp a")').attr('class', 'vote_up_done oneLine');
         $("#"+image_id).find('#voteDown').attr('class', 'vote_down_done oneLine');
         $("#"+image_id).find('#positive').attr('class', 'numberVoted oneLine');
          $("#"+image_id).find('#negative').attr('class', 'numberVoted oneLine');

         $('#message').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Your vote is added!</div>');           
         $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
         });
         },
      error: function() {
         $('#message').text('Error! Please try again!');
      }
   });
}
```

What this script do is to let people to vote on image and when vote is done to make button (thumb up/down) grey i.e. disabled. Normally button must go grey right after the vote is done. Currently the vote is recorded into database but buttons doesn't turn grey and I can vote as much as I want. Once the page is refreshed buttons are disabled.

And if need this is the HTML part from the page with images.

```
<div id="'.$row['image_id'].'" class="pull-right">
    <div id="lineBlock">Ratings: ';
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) { 
          echo '<div class="vote_up_done oneLine"></div>
           <div class="numberVoted oneLine">'.$vote['positive'].'</div>';
        } else {
          echo '<div class="vote_up oneLine" id="voteUp"><a href="#" onclick="vote(\'positive\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].'); return false;"></a></div>
           <div class="number oneLine" id="positive">'.$vote['positive'].'</div>';
        }                       
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
           echo '<div class="vote_down_done oneLine"></div>
                   <div class="numberVoted oneLine">'.$vote['negative'].'</div>';
        } else { 
           echo '<div class="vote_down oneLine" id="voteDown"><a href="#" onclick="vote(\'negative\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].'); return false;"></a></div>
                 <div class="number oneLine" id="negative">'.$vote['negative'].'</div>';
        }                            
        echo '</div><span id="message"></span>
</div>
```

The error in console is this

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #voteUp$("#"+image_id).find("#voteUp a")

Any ideas why buttons doesn't turn grey(disabled) and why is this error?

Comment: It must be quotes mismatch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace this line:

```
$("#"+image_id).find('#voteUp("#"+image_id).find("#voteUp a")').attr('class', 'vote_up_done oneLine');
```

With:

```
$("#"+image_id).find("#voteUp a").attr('class', 'vote_up_done oneLine');
```

This looks like a serious typo that you have. Your quotes are scrambled.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".actions a").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
      return false;
    $(this).closest(".actions").find(".disabled").removeClass("disabled");
    $(this).addClass("disabled");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; text-decoration: none; color: #000;}
li {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; width: 200px; border-radius: 3px; margin: 10px;}
li .actions {overflow: hidden; padding: 3px;}
li .actions a {float: right;}
li .actions a:first-child {float: left;}
li .actions a.disabled, li .actions a.disabled i {color: #999;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/1" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="actions"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Vote Up</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Vote Down</a></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/2" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="actions"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Vote Up</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Vote Down</a></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/3" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="actions"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Vote Up</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Vote Down</a></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/4" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="actions"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Vote Up</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Vote Down</a></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/5" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="actions"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Vote Up</a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Vote Down</a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And please, if someone downvotes, please tell the reason!

Comment: `$("#"+image_id).find('#voteUp').find("#"+image_id)` will always result in 0 results

Comment: @Curt Thank you so much.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, thank you for the answer. It's almost working now. The problem now is that when I click on thumbUP button is voting correctly but it's disabling thumbDOWN button ... not thumbUP.

Comment: @JasonPaddle Ah I see... Can you share the whole script as a working snippet or can you show us a live demo, please?

Comment: @JasonPaddle That looks like a database issue. Even after refresh, it doesn't work. What exactly you want both the buttons to do? We can do it fresh.

Comment: It is working based on cookie. And after vote next 24 hours you can't vote on this image again ( unless you delete your cookies ). Must work like this: When you voteUP the voteUP button should go grey(disabled) and voteDOWN should be active so you can voteDOWN or if you voteDOWN the voteDOWN button should go disabled and voteUP will be active.

Comment: @JasonPaddle Can you have a look at the updated fiddle?

Comment: Yes, I try to make it like this.

Comment: I can use this HTML part but I don't know how to make the ajax part to connect with the add_vote.php script..

Comment: No you don't need to rewrite, but just a few things would clean up your code.

Comment: What exactly? Can you help with this `No you don't need to rewrite, but just a few things..`

Comment: Don't you think it is better to rewrite your code in simpler way like I gave than your complex one?

Comment: Yes, I think is better. But I'm not that good yet. I write this one from one tutorial..

Comment: Okay, will support you to do it. Use this, so that your code is cleaner.

Comment: Okay, thank's. So how would be the ajax part? Do i need to change it? Do I still need cookie part or I will not need it since here the function is disabling the button?

Comment: Sure... You don't need to change the AJAX or cookie part. We just need to change it according to the HTML.

Comment: Don't get it what to change then. I will still need for this `'.$vote['negative'].'` and this `onclick="vote(\'negative\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].');` ... `onclick="vote(\'positive\', \'1\', '.$row['image_id'].');`

Answer (score 4):

The `.find` should be outside the quote, because it's not part of the jquery selector. `'#voteUp'` is a jquery selector and should be in quotes, while `find` is a javascript method that operates on the result of a selector.